# Running Apache and NGINX at the same time

Tags: apache, nginx

I currently have Apache configured and serving content over port 80 and 443.

I wish to serve content over port 8000 using NGINX. I've followed [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-migrate-from-an-apache-web-server-to-nginx-on-an-ubuntu-vps).

in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` I changed

```
server {
       listen 80 default_server;
       ....
```

to

```
server {
       listen 8000 default_server;
       ....
```

According to the guide, this show allow me to access both

```
http://my_ip_or_domain:8000
http://my_ip_or_domain:80
```

at the same time. However, I can access it via port 80, but going over port 8000 returns a `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`. There's no output in `/var/log/nginx/error.log`. How can I access it using port 8000?

Comment: Use `nginx -T` to check the configuration file.

Comment: If both services are running on the same server,  is there a reason for different IP (`my_ip` vs `your_ip`)?

Comment: @RichardSmith It returns syntax is ok and test is succesful.

Comment: Is nginx running at all (`ps aux | grep nginx`)?

Comment: @DusanBajic I'm not entirely certain how to read the output, but it spawns a list including 5 `nginx worker process` in `www-data`. I can post a screen if it helps.

Comment: It is running. Now check the port it is listening on: `sudo netstat -nap | grep LISTE | grep nginx`

Comment: @DusanBajic Ah, this might be important. It appears to listen on `0.0.0.0:8000` and `0:::8000`. It's only listening on localhost, not the ip?

Comment: no, `0.0.0.0` is fine (`127.0.0.1` would be localhost only). Can you try `curl -v my_ip:8000` from the webserver shell.

Comment: Also, you might need to open port 8000 in server firewall :)

Comment: @DusanBajic If I do this from the server (using ssh) it returns a html saying ' Welcome to nginx'. If i do it from a terminal from another machine it returns ' Failed to connect to my_ip port 8000: Timed out'. Firewall shoudn't be the issue, but i'll check just to make sure.

Comment: @DusanBajic It turned out to be the firewall after all..Stupid mistake: I had accidently opened up 8009 instead of 8000. Changed the `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` to listen to 8009 and now it works. Thank you. The commands you provided teached me to better be able to fix issues in the future.

Comment: you are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You have to open the specified port

`$ sudo ufw allow 8000`

This command would open the 8000 port